# Incorrect Javascript Functions?

Tags: javascript, html

I am completely brand new to Javascript. In fact, I'm just an Objective-C programmer looking to implement just a little Javascript into one of my apps. So, the problem is for whatever reason when I call my first function, nothing happens there I don't get the alert. When I call my second function I only get the alert, the button isn't actually clicked.

Code:

```
function myFunction(username, password) {
    alert("Data will be entered");
    document.getElementById('ctl00_plnMain_txtLogin').value = username;
    document.getElementById('ctl00_plnMain_txtPassword').value = password;
}

function click() {
    alert("The button was clicked");
    document.getElementById("ctl00_plnMain_Submit1").click();
}
```

I can seem to run just a regular alert fine, but nothing else??? Is there something wrong in my function?

If it helps, on the website here is the "username" box:

```
<input name="ctl00$plnMain$txtLogin" type="text" maxlength="50" id="ctl00_plnMain_txtLogin" tabindex="1">
```

"password" box:

```
<input name="ctl00$plnMain$txtPassword" type="password" maxlength="255" id="ctl00_plnMain_txtPassword" tabindex="2">
```

the button:

```
<input onclick="if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate(''); " name="ctl00$plnMain$Submit1" type="submit" id="ctl00_plnMain_Submit1" tabindex="3" value="Log In" title="Log in">
```

-- EDIT

Also, I am starting the functions through my objective C code. I grab a js file, then I am able to use its functions on a webpage.

Comment: wat does this do if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate('');

Comment: The problem is nobody is calling those function, where do you want the functions to be called

Comment: Sorry for not explaining that part-I'll update.

Comment: I feel like you need a bit more help here, but I'm struggling to understand what your trying to accomplish - it looks like your setting the value of those inputs to window.username / window.password, I don't think that is what you intend correct?

Comment: On a webpage there are two text boxes, one for a username and one for a password, I was trying to send arguments with my function above to set the text in these boxes to the arguments :D -- Am I setting it in the wrong place? Should I be somewhere else other than document?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) abstraction library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

jQuery provides an 'on' method, it's used to bind events to DOM elements:

```
$('#ctl00_plnMain_Submit1').on('click', function (event) {
    alert("The button was clicked");
}
```

It also provides a nice abstraction for collecting input values:

```
var userName = $('#ctl00_plnMain_txtLogin').val();
```

You can also use it to set the value of an input:

```
$('#ctl00_plnMain_txtLogin').val('New Value for This Input');
```

Populating inputs with a function:

```
function populateInputs (username, password) {
    $('#ctl00_plnMain_txtLogin').val(username);
    $('#ctl00_plnMain_txtPassword').val(password);
}
```

Comment: Bare with me here, I don't know a single thing about Java ! Could I use this method to change the values of text boxes?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example of setting the value of an input.

Comment: Can I shove all of that into a function, using variables for the inputs?

Comment: Yup let me update, my answer - where is the value for the variables coming from?  How will you call the function, just on page load?

Comment: @Not My Name Car your function should work just as well without jquery.  2 small corrections, Java is NOT Javascript, and "Bare with me" means to get naked together...ewww.

Comment: It 'will' work without jQuery, but jQuery insulates you from some of the headaches that can result from supporting multiple browsers

Comment: In my iOS app I load the page, and when I've confirmed the page finished loading I can call functions on the page (using functions from an external JS file) in the simple form of : myFunction(variable,anotherVariable)

Comment: Yeah... I was just wondering if anyone saw an error in the functions that would cause them not to be called? For some reason only the text box setting ones don't get called? (Or the click for that matter). But the alerts work just fine?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want the click function to be called when the button is clicked

You need to specify that then

```
  <input onclick="click()" ....
```